# how to get distinct value from angularjs loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I made a loop in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and i want to get a distinct values from this loop then `push` it to an `array`.

What I got instead, are repetitive values.

The `$scope.Empassignedvacations` returns multiple data from datatable from db. one column from it is vac which displays multiple vacations keys in the db.
What i want to do is to take these keys and distinct them and push them to another `$scope` array. its name is `$scope.checkedvacs`. but i got `2,2,2,2,20,20,20,20`

```
Assignments.getvacations().then(function (response) {
   $scope.vacations = (response.data);

   Assignments.GetEmpassignedvacations($scope.SelectedEmp1.staffkey)
   .then(function (response) {
     $scope.Empassignedvacations = (response.data)
     $scope.checkedvacs.push( $scope.Empassignedvacations.vac );

     angular.forEach($scope.Empassignedvacations, function (e) {
          angular.forEach($scope.AlternateDirector, function (a) {
               if (e.Staff_Key == a.Staff_Key) {
                  $scope.AlternateD = e.AlternateD; 
               }
          })
          angular.forEach($scope.status, function (s) {
               if (e.status == s.stsid) {
                  $scope.sts = s.stsid;
               }
          })
     })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you play with the same value `$scope.Empassignedvacations`.

You push it to the array and after - change it. This is a reason why you get `2,2,2,2,20,20,20,20`

So you can fix it by pushing the **copy** of the value, like:

```
$scope.checkedvacs.push( angular.copy($scope.Empassignedvacations.vac));
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare `$scope.checkedvacs=[]` & `$scope.keys=[]` in globally for standard code practice then try bellow code

```
angular.forEach($scope.Empassignedvacations.vac, function(item) {
  // we check to see whether our object exists
  $scope.keys = item[keyname];
  // if it's not already part of our keys array
  if ($scope.keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
    // push this item to our final output array
    $scope.checkedvacs.push(item);
  }
});
```

remove bellow code and replace your code with first code sample..

```
$scope.checkedvacs.push( $scope.Empassignedvacations.vac );

 angular.forEach($scope.Empassignedvacations, function (e) {
      angular.forEach($scope.AlternateDirector, function (a) {
           if (e.Staff_Key == a.Staff_Key) {
              $scope.AlternateD = e.AlternateD; 
           }
      })
      angular.forEach($scope.status, function (s) {
           if (e.status == s.stsid) {
              $scope.sts = s.stsid;
           }
      })
```

You can also follow bellow link that may be helpful for you
https://tutorialedge.net/javascript/angularjs/removing-duplicates-from-ng-repeat/